# Issues Flexslider mobile view when slides are different heights

Tags: flexslider

First of all I've searched for the solution but couldn't find any..

I'm new at this so I lack experience to solve this, hopefully somebody can help me :)

The Problem:

I use flexslider on my woocommerce product pages. I am having problems only when a product page is opened in mobile browser and when the slides different heights. The first slide is aprox. half the height of the rest of the slides. When opening the product page the last slide lays underneath the first slide and covers the text partially  I have beneath it. (so the first picture and the bottom of the  last slide are showing). When the animation loop is complete and the slider starts over again the problem is gone? This only happens on mobile views, desktop has no problems.

I have this in functions.php:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options', 'sf_update_woo_flexslider_options' );
function sf_update_woo_flexslider_options( $options ) {

```
$options['animation'] = 'fade';
$options['slideshow'] = true;
$options['smoothHeight'] = true;
$options['fadeFirstSlide'] = true;
$options['slideshowSpeed'] = 8000;
$options['animationSpeed'] = 3500;
$options['animationLoop'] = true;
$options['randomize'] = false;
$options['pauseOnAction'] = true;
$options['pauseOnHover'] = true;
$options['startAt'] = 0;
$options['easing'] = "swing";

return $options;
```

}

I have tried several things allready like disabling smoothheight. But I cant figure out whats wrong.
I would really appreciate some help here ;) 
(I'm not an experienced coder, not at all..)

One of the pages where this occurs: https://www.littleleloo.com/shop/large-contemporary-abstract-painting-angels-vs-demons/

Thanks and  have a lovely day!

Best wishes,

Jessica